# Automatically insert a date in database

Tags: oracle

```
create table assignments
( 
  loginid varchar2(6),
  comments varchar2(20), 
  status char(1), 
  given_by varchar2(6),
  courseanddept varchar2(15),
  adate date default sysdate, 
 foreign key(loginid) references login(loginid)
);
```

I have a table of this structure and I'm unable to Insert a `sysdate` automatically. What is the query in order to insert auto `sysdate`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you simply do not explicitly set a value for your date column, the default will be used; for example:

```
insert into assignments( loginid       , 
                         comments      ,
                         status        , 
                         given_by      , 
                         courseanddept 
                        )
                 values ( 'login',
                          'comments',
                          'X',
                          'Y',
                          'unknown'
                        )
```

The resulting data:

```
SQL> select adate from assignments;

ADATE
---------
23-JAN-17
```

If you set a value for the column, the value you set is used and default is ignored:

```
insert into assignments( loginid       , 
                         comments      ,
                         status        , 
                         given_by      , 
                         courseanddept ,
                         adate 
                        )
                 values ( 'login2',
                          'comments2',
                          'Z',
                          'W',
                          'unknown2',
                          date '2016-12-31'
                        )
```

gives:

```
SQL> select adate from assignments;

ADATE
---------
31-DEC-16
```

Same thing if you set a `NULL` value:

```
insert into assignments( loginid       , 
                         comments      ,
                         status        , 
                         given_by      , 
                         courseanddept ,
                         adate 
                        )
                 values ( 'login3',
                          'comments3',
                          'Z',
                          'W',
                          'unknown2',
                          null
                        )
```

gives:

```
SQL> select adate from assignments;

ADATE
---------


SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not give any input for the column  "adate" as you have already mention default sysdate, so whenever you are not giving input while inserting it will update it as sysdate, if you give value it will take the value and ignore sysdate. Please refer above examples. you will understand clearly.